# How to display Category list at search result page in magento..?

Tags: magento

I want to display categories instead of product result. if anyone search product name, then result should be category which contains that product.
Is it possible in magento?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento does not have this feature.

**Magento search depends on product and it Eav Attributes.**

If you want **then you need create custom extension and custom module**

Comment: is any extension available to do it same.

Comment: May be not.. not sure 100%